# Beautiful Soup Pulling URL from Script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a url off of a page source. The URL I need is buried within a script as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">[
{
"@context":"http://schema.org","
@type":"NewsArticle",
"articleBody":"\n\n[#iframe: https://audm.herokuapp.com/player-embed?pub=newyorker&articleID=60db43bb53829a9732660612](100%x90)\n\n+++dropcap\n\n
```

And then it continues on from there, including all the text on the entire page.

What I'm trying to pull is "https://audm.herokuapp.com/player-embed?pub=newyorker&articleID=60db43bb53829a9732660612"

I know how to use BS4 to pull info from scripts, as follows:

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
print data['articlebody']
```

As an example, but I'm not sure how to specify the actual link portion between "#iframe:" and the closed bracket. I could maybe use a regex to match the pattern and pull the url from between these two strings, but are there other, better solutions?

Comment: Personally I think regex is your best solution. It's very quick and will be quite reliable in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular-Expressions pattern to find the link.
For example:

```
re.search(r"\[#iframe: (.*?)]", script_tag).group(1)
```

In your case:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context":"http://schema.org","
@type":"NewsArticle",
"articleBody":"\n\n[#iframe: https://audm.herokuapp.com/player-embed?pub=newyorker&articleID=60db43bb53829a9732660612](100%x90)\n\n+++dropcap\n\n
</script>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script_tag = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").string

link = re.search(r"\[#iframe: (.*?)]", script_tag).group(1)
print(link)
```

Outptut:

```
https://audm.herokuapp.com/player-embed?pub=newyorker&articleID=60db43bb53829a9732660612
```